# How to show notification with ringing alarm in background?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-preferences, android-alarms

guys, I am developing an alarm app in which alarm is triggering good and at the right time but the drawback is when the alarm is ringing with an activity then when we press the home button too it is ringing the real problem is when the application is closed by pressing the home button and pressing or swiping close all apps the application getting destroyed I need something like Google does like showing a notification and playing sound even if the application is closed.

So I think someone is having Idea about this issue.

Here is what from Google Clock

[Googel Clock image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiVGE.jpg)

Because of android Q, I had developed something that when the user is alive at the time of alarm then we just show notification with the help of this.

```
public class DismissAlarmNotificationController {

public final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
public static final String INTENT_KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID = "notificationId";
public final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel-01";
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private Context context;
private final int IMPORTANCE = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

public DismissAlarmNotificationController(Context context) {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
}

public void showNotification() {

    Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(context, DismissAlarmActivity.class);
    PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID, getChannelName(), IMPORTANCE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_on_notification)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.dismiss_alarm_notification_title))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.dismiss_alarm_notification_body, getCurrentTime()))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(getDismissNotificationAction())
            .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true);

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());

}

public String getChannelName() {
    return context.getString(R.string.app_name) + "Channel";
}

public void cancelNotification() {
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}

private NotificationCompat.Action getDismissNotificationAction() {
    Intent dismissIntent = new Intent(context, DismissNotificationReceiver.class);
    dismissIntent.putExtra(INTENT_KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_ID);

    PendingIntent dismissNotificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, dismissIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    return new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
            0,
            context.getString(R.string.dismiss_alarm_notification_dismiss_button_title),
            dismissNotificationPendingIntent)
            .build();
}

private String getCurrentTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date currentTime = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(currentTime);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [Android's WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)!

It lets you run background works even if the app is closed or the phone has been restarted.
Hope it will help!